# Optimizing my project's scenario object

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, query-optimization

My queryScenario.php file is loading too slowly, avg 28sec. What can I do to decrease this with queries and loops?
I have no idea how to deal with it, since I know almost nothing about optimizing PHP.

Thanks.

This is my queryScenario.php file:

```
<?php
        include("database.php");
        include("dataModel.php");

        if(!isset($_SESSION))
            session_start();

        //$userId = 1; // This variable will be obtained from the session
        $userId = $_SESSION['userIdNumber'];
        //$selectedUserLandId = $_GET['id']; // This variable may be defined as a session variable
        $selectedUserLandId = $_SESSION['selectedUserLandId'];

        // load the related user based model tables (dynamic data)
        $landLiteral = dbGetUserLandByLandId($userId, $selectedUserLandId); 
        if (count($landLiteral)< 1){
            // TODO: Throw an exception here          
        }
        $landLiteralSelected = $landLiteral[0];
        $userLand = new Land();
        $userLand->id = $landLiteralSelected["id"];
        $userLand->name = $landLiteralSelected["name"];
        $userLand->desc = $landLiteralSelected["description"];
        $landmap = dbGetLandmapById($landLiteralSelected["id"]);
        $userLand->mapimage = $landmap[0]["mapimage"];
        $geopos = dbGetGeoposById($landLiteralSelected["geopos_id"]);
        $userLand->lat = $geopos[0]["lat"];
        $userLand->lng = $geopos[0]["lng"] ;
        $userLand->type = $landLiteralSelected["landenum_id"];
        $sectorsLiteral = dbGetSectorsByLandId($userLand->id);
        foreach ($sectorsLiteral as $sectorLiteral){
           $sector = new Sector();
            $sector->id = $sectorLiteral["id"];
            $sector->name = $sectorLiteral["name"];
            $sector->desc = $sectorLiteral["description"];
            $geoposSector = dbGetGeoposById($sectorLiteral["geopos_id"]);
            $sector->lat = $geoposSector[0]["lat"];
            $sector->lng = $geoposSector[0]["lng"] ;
            $userLand->sectionList[] = $sector;

            $devicesLiteral = dbGetDevicesBySectorId($sector->id);
            foreach ($devicesLiteral as $deviceLiteral){
                $device = new Device();
                $device->id = $deviceLiteral["id"];
                $device->sceneName = $deviceLiteral["scenename"];
                $device->sceneDesc = $deviceLiteral["scenedescription"];
                $mapinfoDevice = dbGetMapInfoById($deviceLiteral["mapitem_id"]);
                $device->mapInfo[] = $mapinfoDevice[0];
                $geoposDevice = dbGetGeoposById($deviceLiteral["geopos_id"]);
                $device->lat = $geoposDevice[0]["lat"];
                $device->lng = $geoposDevice[0]["lng"];
                $device->type = $deviceLiteral["deviceenum_id"];
                $device->serialNo = $deviceLiteral["serialNo"];
                $sector->deviceList[] = $device;

                // NOW THE MODULES
                $modulesLiteral = dbGetDeviceModulesByDeviceType($device->type);

                foreach($modulesLiteral as $moduleLiteralList){
                    foreach ($moduleLiteralList as $moduleLiteral){
                        $module = new Module();
                        $module->id = $moduleLiteral["id"];
                        $module->type = $moduleLiteral["moduleenum_id"];
                        $module->unit = $moduleLiteral["unit"];
                        $module->subid = dbGetSubIdOfModule($module->id);
                        $deviceStateLiteral=dbGetDeviceStates($device->id);

                        if (count($deviceStateLiteral) > 0){
                            $moduleState=new ModuleState();
                            $moduleState->pendingState=$deviceStateLiteral[0]["pending_state"];
                            $moduleState->desiredState=$deviceStateLiteral[0]["desired_state"];
                            $moduleState->currentState=$deviceStateLiteral[0]["current_state"];
                            $module->moduleState=$moduleState;
                        }
                        $moduleDataLiteral=dbGetLastDeviceModuleData($device->id,$module->id);
                        $moduleData=new ModuleData();
                        if (count($moduleDataLiteral) > 0){
                            $moduleData->data=$moduleDataLiteral[0]["value"]." ".$module->unit;
                            $moduleData->timeStamp=$moduleDataLiteral[0]["timestamp"];
                        }else{
                               $moduleData->data="Veri Yok";
                               $moduleData->timeStamp="Veri Yok";
                        }
                              $module->moduleData=$moduleData;

                        $device->moduleList[] = $module;

                        // NOW THE MODULE SPECS
                        // First, get the default specs
                        $specsLiteral = dbGetDefaultSpecsByModuleId($module->id);

                        foreach($specsLiteral as $specLiteral){
                            $spec = new Spec();
                            $spec->type = $specLiteral["specenum_id"];
                            $spec->editable = $specLiteral["editable"];
                            $spec->value = $specLiteral["default"];

                            // NOW LOOK FOR UPDATED SPEC FOR THIS DEVICE MODULE AND SPEC
                            $updatedSpecLiteral = dbGetUpdatedDeviceSpec($device->id, $module->id, $spec->type);

                            if ($updatedSpecLiteral){
                               $spec->value = $updatedSpecLiteral[0]["specvalue"];
                            }

                            $module->specList[] = $spec;
                        }
                    }           
                }
            }
        }
        if(!(isset($_GET["nonEcho"]) && $_GET["nonEcho"]=="yes"))
            echo json_encode($userLand);

?>
```

These are data models:

```
<?php
class Node {
    public $id;
}

class SpatialNode extends Node {
    public $lat = 0;
    public $lng = 0;
}

class Land extends SpatialNode{
    public $name;
    public $desc = "";
    public $type;
    public $sectionList = array();
    public $mapimage;
}

class Sector extends SpatialNode{
    public $name;
    public $desc = "";
    public $deviceList = array();
}

class Device extends SpatialNode{
    public $sceneName;
    public $sceneDesc;
    public $type;
    public $desc = "";
    public $serialNo;
    public $installationDate = "";
    public $moduleList = array();
    public $mapInfo = array();
}

class Module extends Node{
    public $type;
    public $unit = "";
    public $subid;
    public $specList = array();
    public $moduleData;
    public $moduleState;
}

class ModuleData{
    public $data;
    public $timeStamp;
}
class ModuleState{
    public $pendingState;
    public $desiredState;
    public $currentState;
}
class Spec{
    public $type;
    public $value;
    public $editable;
}


class DeviceStatus{
    public $name;
    public $address;
    public $pendingState;
    public $desiredState;
}

?>
```

These are queries:

```
<?php
//include("dataModel.php");

function dbConnect() {
    $dbhost = 'XXXXXXXX';
    $dbuser = 'XXXXX';
    $dbpass = 'XXXXXXXXX';

    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    if (!$conn) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db('XXXXXXXXX', $conn);
    mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
    return $conn;
}

function executeSQL($sql) {
    $conn = dbConnect();

    $values = array();
    $retval = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

    if (!$retval) {
        die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        array_push($values, $row);
    }

    return $values;
}

function executeSQLForPersist($sql){
    $conn = dbConnect();


    $retval = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

    return $retval;
}

function dbGetLandsByUserId($userId){
    $sql  = "SELECT * FROM land WHERE user_id=$userId or user_id=1 ";
    return executeSQL($sql);
}

function dbGetUserLandByLandId($userId, $landId){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM land WHERE user_id=$userId AND id=$landId UNION SELECT * FROM land WHERE user_id=1 AND id=1";
    return executeSQL($sql);
}

function dbGetGeoposById($geoId){
    $sql  = "SELECT * FROM geoposition WHERE id=$geoId";
    return executeSQL($sql);
}
function dbGetLandmapById($id){
    $sql  = "SELECT * FROM landimages WHERE land_id=$id";
    return executeSQL($sql);
}
function dbGetMapInfoById($id) {
    $sql  = "SELECT * FROM mapitems WHERE id=$id";
    return executeSQL($sql);
}

function dbGetEnums(){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM enums";
    return executeSQL($sql);
}

function dbGetSceneDevices(){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM scenedevices";
    return executeSQL($sql);
}


function dbGetSectorsByLandId($landId){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM sector WHERE land_id=$landId";
    return executeSQL($sql);
}

function dbGetDevicesBySectorId($sectorId){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM scenedevices WHERE sector_id=$sectorId";
    return executeSQL($sql);
}

function dbGetDeviceModulesByDeviceType($deviceTypeId){
     $sql = "SELECT module_id FROM devicedef WHERE deviceenum_id=$deviceTypeId";
     $moduleIdsLiteral = executeSQL($sql);

     $modulesLiteralList = array();
     foreach ($moduleIdsLiteral as $moduleIdLiteral){
         $moduleId = $moduleIdLiteral["module_id"];
         $sqlModuleQuery = "SELECT * FROM module WHERE id=$moduleId";
         $modulesLiteralList[] = executeSQL($sqlModuleQuery);

     }
     return $modulesLiteralList;
}

function dbGetDefaultSpecsByModuleId($moduleId){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM module_specs WHERE module_id=$moduleId";
    return executeSQL($sql);
}

function dbGetUpdatedDeviceSpec($deviceId, $moduleId, $specId){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=$deviceId AND module_id=$moduleId AND specenum_id=$specId";
    return executeSQL($sql);
}

function dbGetProfileLandImageByLandId($landId){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM landimages WHERE land_id=$landId AND profile=1";
    return executeSQL($sql);
}


function dbGetSubIdOfModule($moduleId){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM devicedef WHERE module_id='$moduleId'";
    $idLiteral = executeSQL($sql);
    if(count($idLiteral) != 0) {
        return $idLiteral[0]["subid"];
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}

function dbGetModuleIdByModuleEnumId($moduleEnumId){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM module WHERE moduleenum_id=$moduleEnumId";
    $idLiteral = executeSQL($sql);
    if (count($idLiteral) == 1){
        return $idLiteral[0]['id'];
    }else{
        return -1;
    }
}

function dbGetAllDeviceModuleData($devId, $modId){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM realtimedevicedata WHERE scenedevice_id=$devId AND module_id=$modId ORDER BY timestamp LIMIT 0, 500"; //TODO.
    return executeSQL($sql);
}
function dbGetLastDeviceModuleData($devId, $modId){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM realtimedevicedata WHERE scenedevice_id=$devId AND module_id=$modId ORDER BY timestamp desc limit 1";
    return executeSQL($sql);   
}

function dbGetLastDayDeviceModuleData($devId, $modId){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM realtimedevicedata WHERE scenedevice_id=$devId AND module_id=$modId AND timestamp>=SYSDATE()-INTERVAL 1 DAY ORDER BY timestamp";
    return executeSQL($sql);   
}

function dbGetIntervalDeviceModuleData($devId, $modId, $startDate, $endDate){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM realtimedevicedata WHERE scenedevice_id=$devId AND module_id=$modId AND timestamp>='$startDate' AND timestamp<='$endDate' ORDER BY timestamp";
    return executeSQL($sql);   
}

function dbGetDeviceStates($devId) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=$devId";
    return executeSQL($sql);   
}

function dbGetAllDeviceStates($imei) {
    $sql  = "SELECT  scenedevices.scenename, scenedevices.serialNo, deviceprefs.pending_state, ".
            "deviceprefs.desired_state FROM  scenedevices, deviceprefs ". 
        "WHERE  scenedevices.parentId = '".$imei."' AND scenedevices.id = deviceprefs.scenedevice_id ";
    return executeSQL($sql);
}


?>
```

Comment: Whoa! Props to whoever has the patience to go through that

Comment: I recommend you looking into APC for caching and optimizing PHP intermediate code.

Comment: You have such a HUMONGOUS foreach loop! No wonder it's taking so long to execute :/

Comment: So, Is there anything to do to deal with it? :(

Comment: Take a look at PDOs fetchObject http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php (puts a result set directly into an object).  Stop using "select *", select only named fields needed (unless you do actually need them all).

Comment: Will fethObject works faster? I will edit all my statements about your proposal to edit "select *". Thanks!.

Comment: I tried to count how many queries are working and result suprised me : just 111.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize that the reason of my code is running slow is that realtimedevicedata table is too large(approx 120MB and has 50K records) and I try to order this table before select no records. To avoid this, I change my code to fetch first 500 records from that table and then order the table. This breaks the chains.

Thanks to all who wanted to help, and sorry for the time loose.
Have a good day.

SQL changes :

Old one :

```
$sql = "SELECT value, timestamp FROM realtimedevicedata WHERE scenedevice_id=$devId AND module_id=$modId ORDER BY timestamp desc limit 0,1";
```

New one:

```
$sql = "SELECT value, timestamp FROM (SELECT DISTINCT scenedevice_id, value, timestamp FROM realtimedevicedata AS K WHERE K.scenedevice_id=$devId AND K.module_id=$modId LIMIT 0,100) AS M ORDER BY M.timestamp desc Limit 0,1";
```

Proof of realtimedevicedata is a bad girl:

```
0.02 secs : SELECT * FROM land WHERE user_id=2 AND id=1 UNION SELECT * FROM land WHERE user_id=1 AND id=1
0.11 secs : SELECT mapimage FROM landimages WHERE land_id=1 LIMIT 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT lat,lng FROM geoposition WHERE id=1 LIMIT 0,1
0.06 secs : SELECT id, name, description, geopos_id FROM sector WHERE land_id=1
0.00 secs : SELECT lat,lng FROM geoposition WHERE id=2 LIMIT 0,1
0.03 secs : SELECT id,scenename,scenedescription,mapitem_id,geopos_id,deviceenum_id,serialNo FROM scenedevices WHERE sector_id=1
0.00 secs : SELECT * FROM mapitems WHERE id=1
0.00 secs : SELECT lat,lng FROM geoposition WHERE id=47 LIMIT 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT module_id FROM devicedef WHERE deviceenum_id=6
0.00 secs : SELECT id, moduleenum_id, unit FROM module WHERE id=11
0.00 secs : SELECT subid FROM devicedef WHERE module_id='11'
0.00 secs : SELECT pending_state, desired_state, current_state FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=1
0.15 secs : SELECT value, timestamp FROM realtimedevicedata WHERE scenedevice_id=1 AND module_id=11 ORDER BY timestamp desc limit 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT `specenum_id`, `editable`, `default` FROM module_specs WHERE module_id=11
0.00 secs : SELECT * FROM mapitems WHERE id=3
0.00 secs : SELECT lat,lng FROM geoposition WHERE id=2 LIMIT 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT module_id FROM devicedef WHERE deviceenum_id=4
0.00 secs : SELECT id, moduleenum_id, unit FROM module WHERE id=1
0.00 secs : SELECT id, moduleenum_id, unit FROM module WHERE id=2
0.00 secs : SELECT id, moduleenum_id, unit FROM module WHERE id=3
0.00 secs : SELECT id, moduleenum_id, unit FROM module WHERE id=10
0.00 secs : SELECT subid FROM devicedef WHERE module_id='1'
0.00 secs : SELECT pending_state, desired_state, current_state FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=2
9.41 secs : SELECT value, timestamp FROM realtimedevicedata WHERE scenedevice_id=2 AND module_id=1 ORDER BY timestamp desc limit 0,1
0.01 secs : SELECT `specenum_id`, `editable`, `default` FROM module_specs WHERE module_id=1
0.02 secs : SELECT specvalue FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=2 AND module_id=1 AND specenum_id=14
0.00 secs : SELECT specvalue FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=2 AND module_id=1 AND specenum_id=15
0.00 secs : SELECT specvalue FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=2 AND module_id=1 AND specenum_id=18
0.00 secs : SELECT subid FROM devicedef WHERE module_id='2'
0.00 secs : SELECT pending_state, desired_state, current_state FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=2
6.84 secs : SELECT value, timestamp FROM realtimedevicedata WHERE scenedevice_id=2 AND module_id=2 ORDER BY timestamp desc limit 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT `specenum_id`, `editable`, `default` FROM module_specs WHERE module_id=2
0.01 secs : SELECT specvalue FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=2 AND module_id=2 AND specenum_id=14
0.00 secs : SELECT specvalue FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=2 AND module_id=2 AND specenum_id=15
0.00 secs : SELECT specvalue FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=2 AND module_id=2 AND specenum_id=18
0.02 secs : SELECT subid FROM devicedef WHERE module_id='3'
0.00 secs : SELECT pending_state, desired_state, current_state FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=2
4.44 secs : SELECT value, timestamp FROM realtimedevicedata WHERE scenedevice_id=2 AND module_id=3 ORDER BY timestamp desc limit 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT `specenum_id`, `editable`, `default` FROM module_specs WHERE module_id=3
0.00 secs : SELECT specvalue FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=2 AND module_id=3 AND specenum_id=14
0.00 secs : SELECT specvalue FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=2 AND module_id=3 AND specenum_id=15
0.00 secs : SELECT specvalue FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=2 AND module_id=3 AND specenum_id=18
0.00 secs : SELECT subid FROM devicedef WHERE module_id='10'
0.00 secs : SELECT pending_state, desired_state, current_state FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=2
9.27 secs : SELECT value, timestamp FROM realtimedevicedata WHERE scenedevice_id=2 AND module_id=10 ORDER BY timestamp desc limit 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT `specenum_id`, `editable`, `default` FROM module_specs WHERE module_id=10
0.01 secs : SELECT * FROM mapitems WHERE id=5
0.01 secs : SELECT lat,lng FROM geoposition WHERE id=44 LIMIT 0,1
0.02 secs : SELECT module_id FROM devicedef WHERE deviceenum_id=5
0.00 secs : SELECT id, moduleenum_id, unit FROM module WHERE id=4
0.00 secs : SELECT id, moduleenum_id, unit FROM module WHERE id=10
0.00 secs : SELECT subid FROM devicedef WHERE module_id='4'
0.02 secs : SELECT pending_state, desired_state, current_state FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=4
0.01 secs : SELECT value, timestamp FROM realtimedevicedata WHERE scenedevice_id=4 AND module_id=4 ORDER BY timestamp desc limit 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT `specenum_id`, `editable`, `default` FROM module_specs WHERE module_id=4
0.00 secs : SELECT subid FROM devicedef WHERE module_id='10'
0.00 secs : SELECT pending_state, desired_state, current_state FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=4
0.00 secs : SELECT value, timestamp FROM realtimedevicedata WHERE scenedevice_id=4 AND module_id=10 ORDER BY timestamp desc limit 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT `specenum_id`, `editable`, `default` FROM module_specs WHERE module_id=10
0.00 secs : SELECT * FROM mapitems WHERE id=6
0.00 secs : SELECT lat,lng FROM geoposition WHERE id=45 LIMIT 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT module_id FROM devicedef WHERE deviceenum_id=31
0.00 secs : SELECT id, moduleenum_id, unit FROM module WHERE id=4
0.00 secs : SELECT subid FROM devicedef WHERE module_id='4'
0.00 secs : SELECT pending_state, desired_state, current_state FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=5
0.00 secs : SELECT value, timestamp FROM realtimedevicedata WHERE scenedevice_id=5 AND module_id=4 ORDER BY timestamp desc limit 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT `specenum_id`, `editable`, `default` FROM module_specs WHERE module_id=4
0.00 secs : SELECT lat,lng FROM geoposition WHERE id=3 LIMIT 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT id,scenename,scenedescription,mapitem_id,geopos_id,deviceenum_id,serialNo FROM scenedevices WHERE sector_id=2
0.00 secs : SELECT * FROM mapitems WHERE id=4
0.00 secs : SELECT lat,lng FROM geoposition WHERE id=3 LIMIT 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT module_id FROM devicedef WHERE deviceenum_id=29
0.00 secs : SELECT id, moduleenum_id, unit FROM module WHERE id=1
0.00 secs : SELECT id, moduleenum_id, unit FROM module WHERE id=2
0.00 secs : SELECT id, moduleenum_id, unit FROM module WHERE id=9
0.00 secs : SELECT id, moduleenum_id, unit FROM module WHERE id=10
0.00 secs : SELECT subid FROM devicedef WHERE module_id='1'
0.00 secs : SELECT pending_state, desired_state, current_state FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=3
4.34 secs : SELECT value, timestamp FROM realtimedevicedata WHERE scenedevice_id=3 AND module_id=1 ORDER BY timestamp desc limit 0,1
0.01 secs : SELECT `specenum_id`, `editable`, `default` FROM module_specs WHERE module_id=1
0.03 secs : SELECT specvalue FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=3 AND module_id=1 AND specenum_id=14
0.00 secs : SELECT specvalue FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=3 AND module_id=1 AND specenum_id=15
0.00 secs : SELECT specvalue FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=3 AND module_id=1 AND specenum_id=18
0.00 secs : SELECT subid FROM devicedef WHERE module_id='2'
0.00 secs : SELECT pending_state, desired_state, current_state FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=3
11.86 secs : SELECT value, timestamp FROM realtimedevicedata WHERE scenedevice_id=3 AND module_id=2 ORDER BY timestamp desc limit 0,1
0.02 secs : SELECT `specenum_id`, `editable`, `default` FROM module_specs WHERE module_id=2
0.05 secs : SELECT specvalue FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=3 AND module_id=2 AND specenum_id=14
0.00 secs : SELECT specvalue FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=3 AND module_id=2 AND specenum_id=15
0.00 secs : SELECT specvalue FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=3 AND module_id=2 AND specenum_id=18
0.04 secs : SELECT subid FROM devicedef WHERE module_id='9'
0.00 secs : SELECT pending_state, desired_state, current_state FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=3
4.25 secs : SELECT value, timestamp FROM realtimedevicedata WHERE scenedevice_id=3 AND module_id=9 ORDER BY timestamp desc limit 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT `specenum_id`, `editable`, `default` FROM module_specs WHERE module_id=9
0.00 secs : SELECT subid FROM devicedef WHERE module_id='10'
0.00 secs : SELECT pending_state, desired_state, current_state FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=3
2.71 secs : SELECT value, timestamp FROM realtimedevicedata WHERE scenedevice_id=3 AND module_id=10 ORDER BY timestamp desc limit 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT `specenum_id`, `editable`, `default` FROM module_specs WHERE module_id=10
0.00 secs : SELECT * FROM mapitems WHERE id=7
0.05 secs : SELECT lat,lng FROM geoposition WHERE id=46 LIMIT 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT module_id FROM devicedef WHERE deviceenum_id=5
0.01 secs : SELECT id, moduleenum_id, unit FROM module WHERE id=4
0.00 secs : SELECT id, moduleenum_id, unit FROM module WHERE id=10
0.00 secs : SELECT subid FROM devicedef WHERE module_id='4'
0.01 secs : SELECT pending_state, desired_state, current_state FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=6
0.00 secs : SELECT value, timestamp FROM realtimedevicedata WHERE scenedevice_id=6 AND module_id=4 ORDER BY timestamp desc limit 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT `specenum_id`, `editable`, `default` FROM module_specs WHERE module_id=4
0.00 secs : SELECT subid FROM devicedef WHERE module_id='10'
0.00 secs : SELECT pending_state, desired_state, current_state FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=6
0.00 secs : SELECT value, timestamp FROM realtimedevicedata WHERE scenedevice_id=6 AND module_id=10 ORDER BY timestamp desc limit 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT `specenum_id`, `editable`, `default` FROM module_specs WHERE module_id=10
```

Now, she promise me to be a nice girl :)

```
0.00 secs : SELECT * FROM land WHERE user_id=2 AND id=1 UNION SELECT * FROM land WHERE user_id=1 AND id=1
0.00 secs : SELECT mapimage FROM landimages WHERE land_id=1 LIMIT 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT lat,lng FROM geoposition WHERE id=1 LIMIT 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT id, name, description, geopos_id FROM sector WHERE land_id=1
0.00 secs : SELECT lat,lng FROM geoposition WHERE id=2 LIMIT 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT id,scenename,scenedescription,mapitem_id,geopos_id,deviceenum_id,serialNo FROM scenedevices WHERE sector_id=1
0.00 secs : SELECT * FROM mapitems WHERE id=1
0.00 secs : SELECT lat,lng FROM geoposition WHERE id=47 LIMIT 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT module_id FROM devicedef WHERE deviceenum_id=6
0.00 secs : SELECT id, moduleenum_id, unit FROM module WHERE id=11
0.00 secs : SELECT subid FROM devicedef WHERE module_id='11'
0.00 secs : SELECT pending_state, desired_state, current_state FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=1
0.00 secs : SELECT value, timestamp FROM (SELECT DISTINCT scenedevice_id, value, timestamp FROM realtimedevicedata AS K WHERE K.scenedevice_id=1 AND K.module_id=11 LIMIT 0,100) AS M ORDER BY M.timestamp desc Limit 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT `specenum_id`, `editable`, `default` FROM module_specs WHERE module_id=11
0.00 secs : SELECT * FROM mapitems WHERE id=3
0.00 secs : SELECT lat,lng FROM geoposition WHERE id=2 LIMIT 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT module_id FROM devicedef WHERE deviceenum_id=4
0.00 secs : SELECT id, moduleenum_id, unit FROM module WHERE id=1
0.00 secs : SELECT id, moduleenum_id, unit FROM module WHERE id=2
0.00 secs : SELECT id, moduleenum_id, unit FROM module WHERE id=3
0.00 secs : SELECT id, moduleenum_id, unit FROM module WHERE id=10
0.00 secs : SELECT subid FROM devicedef WHERE module_id='1'
0.00 secs : SELECT pending_state, desired_state, current_state FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=2
0.00 secs : SELECT value, timestamp FROM (SELECT DISTINCT scenedevice_id, value, timestamp FROM realtimedevicedata AS K WHERE K.scenedevice_id=2 AND K.module_id=1 LIMIT 0,100) AS M ORDER BY M.timestamp desc Limit 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT `specenum_id`, `editable`, `default` FROM module_specs WHERE module_id=1
0.00 secs : SELECT specvalue FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=2 AND module_id=1 AND specenum_id=14
0.00 secs : SELECT specvalue FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=2 AND module_id=1 AND specenum_id=15
0.00 secs : SELECT specvalue FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=2 AND module_id=1 AND specenum_id=18
0.00 secs : SELECT subid FROM devicedef WHERE module_id='2'
0.00 secs : SELECT pending_state, desired_state, current_state FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=2
0.00 secs : SELECT value, timestamp FROM (SELECT DISTINCT scenedevice_id, value, timestamp FROM realtimedevicedata AS K WHERE K.scenedevice_id=2 AND K.module_id=2 LIMIT 0,100) AS M ORDER BY M.timestamp desc Limit 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT `specenum_id`, `editable`, `default` FROM module_specs WHERE module_id=2
0.00 secs : SELECT specvalue FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=2 AND module_id=2 AND specenum_id=14
0.00 secs : SELECT specvalue FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=2 AND module_id=2 AND specenum_id=15
0.00 secs : SELECT specvalue FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=2 AND module_id=2 AND specenum_id=18
0.00 secs : SELECT subid FROM devicedef WHERE module_id='3'
0.00 secs : SELECT pending_state, desired_state, current_state FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=2
0.00 secs : SELECT value, timestamp FROM (SELECT DISTINCT scenedevice_id, value, timestamp FROM realtimedevicedata AS K WHERE K.scenedevice_id=2 AND K.module_id=3 LIMIT 0,100) AS M ORDER BY M.timestamp desc Limit 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT `specenum_id`, `editable`, `default` FROM module_specs WHERE module_id=3
0.00 secs : SELECT specvalue FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=2 AND module_id=3 AND specenum_id=14
0.00 secs : SELECT specvalue FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=2 AND module_id=3 AND specenum_id=15
0.00 secs : SELECT specvalue FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=2 AND module_id=3 AND specenum_id=18
0.00 secs : SELECT subid FROM devicedef WHERE module_id='10'
0.00 secs : SELECT pending_state, desired_state, current_state FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=2
0.00 secs : SELECT value, timestamp FROM (SELECT DISTINCT scenedevice_id, value, timestamp FROM realtimedevicedata AS K WHERE K.scenedevice_id=2 AND K.module_id=10 LIMIT 0,100) AS M ORDER BY M.timestamp desc Limit 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT `specenum_id`, `editable`, `default` FROM module_specs WHERE module_id=10
0.00 secs : SELECT * FROM mapitems WHERE id=5
0.00 secs : SELECT lat,lng FROM geoposition WHERE id=44 LIMIT 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT module_id FROM devicedef WHERE deviceenum_id=5
0.00 secs : SELECT id, moduleenum_id, unit FROM module WHERE id=4
0.00 secs : SELECT id, moduleenum_id, unit FROM module WHERE id=10
0.00 secs : SELECT subid FROM devicedef WHERE module_id='4'
0.00 secs : SELECT pending_state, desired_state, current_state FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=4
0.00 secs : SELECT value, timestamp FROM (SELECT DISTINCT scenedevice_id, value, timestamp FROM realtimedevicedata AS K WHERE K.scenedevice_id=4 AND K.module_id=4 LIMIT 0,100) AS M ORDER BY M.timestamp desc Limit 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT `specenum_id`, `editable`, `default` FROM module_specs WHERE module_id=4
0.00 secs : SELECT subid FROM devicedef WHERE module_id='10'
0.00 secs : SELECT pending_state, desired_state, current_state FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=4
0.00 secs : SELECT value, timestamp FROM (SELECT DISTINCT scenedevice_id, value, timestamp FROM realtimedevicedata AS K WHERE K.scenedevice_id=4 AND K.module_id=10 LIMIT 0,100) AS M ORDER BY M.timestamp desc Limit 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT `specenum_id`, `editable`, `default` FROM module_specs WHERE module_id=10
0.00 secs : SELECT * FROM mapitems WHERE id=6
0.00 secs : SELECT lat,lng FROM geoposition WHERE id=45 LIMIT 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT module_id FROM devicedef WHERE deviceenum_id=31
0.00 secs : SELECT id, moduleenum_id, unit FROM module WHERE id=4
0.00 secs : SELECT subid FROM devicedef WHERE module_id='4'
0.00 secs : SELECT pending_state, desired_state, current_state FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=5
0.00 secs : SELECT value, timestamp FROM (SELECT DISTINCT scenedevice_id, value, timestamp FROM realtimedevicedata AS K WHERE K.scenedevice_id=5 AND K.module_id=4 LIMIT 0,100) AS M ORDER BY M.timestamp desc Limit 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT `specenum_id`, `editable`, `default` FROM module_specs WHERE module_id=4
0.00 secs : SELECT lat,lng FROM geoposition WHERE id=3 LIMIT 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT id,scenename,scenedescription,mapitem_id,geopos_id,deviceenum_id,serialNo FROM scenedevices WHERE sector_id=2
0.00 secs : SELECT * FROM mapitems WHERE id=4
0.00 secs : SELECT lat,lng FROM geoposition WHERE id=3 LIMIT 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT module_id FROM devicedef WHERE deviceenum_id=29
0.00 secs : SELECT id, moduleenum_id, unit FROM module WHERE id=1
0.00 secs : SELECT id, moduleenum_id, unit FROM module WHERE id=2
0.00 secs : SELECT id, moduleenum_id, unit FROM module WHERE id=9
0.00 secs : SELECT id, moduleenum_id, unit FROM module WHERE id=10
0.00 secs : SELECT subid FROM devicedef WHERE module_id='1'
0.00 secs : SELECT pending_state, desired_state, current_state FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=3
0.00 secs : SELECT value, timestamp FROM (SELECT DISTINCT scenedevice_id, value, timestamp FROM realtimedevicedata AS K WHERE K.scenedevice_id=3 AND K.module_id=1 LIMIT 0,100) AS M ORDER BY M.timestamp desc Limit 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT `specenum_id`, `editable`, `default` FROM module_specs WHERE module_id=1
0.00 secs : SELECT specvalue FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=3 AND module_id=1 AND specenum_id=14
0.00 secs : SELECT specvalue FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=3 AND module_id=1 AND specenum_id=15
0.00 secs : SELECT specvalue FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=3 AND module_id=1 AND specenum_id=18
0.00 secs : SELECT subid FROM devicedef WHERE module_id='2'
0.00 secs : SELECT pending_state, desired_state, current_state FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=3
0.00 secs : SELECT value, timestamp FROM (SELECT DISTINCT scenedevice_id, value, timestamp FROM realtimedevicedata AS K WHERE K.scenedevice_id=3 AND K.module_id=2 LIMIT 0,100) AS M ORDER BY M.timestamp desc Limit 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT `specenum_id`, `editable`, `default` FROM module_specs WHERE module_id=2
0.00 secs : SELECT specvalue FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=3 AND module_id=2 AND specenum_id=14
0.00 secs : SELECT specvalue FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=3 AND module_id=2 AND specenum_id=15
0.00 secs : SELECT specvalue FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=3 AND module_id=2 AND specenum_id=18
0.00 secs : SELECT subid FROM devicedef WHERE module_id='9'
0.00 secs : SELECT pending_state, desired_state, current_state FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=3
0.00 secs : SELECT value, timestamp FROM (SELECT DISTINCT scenedevice_id, value, timestamp FROM realtimedevicedata AS K WHERE K.scenedevice_id=3 AND K.module_id=9 LIMIT 0,100) AS M ORDER BY M.timestamp desc Limit 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT `specenum_id`, `editable`, `default` FROM module_specs WHERE module_id=9
0.00 secs : SELECT subid FROM devicedef WHERE module_id='10'
0.00 secs : SELECT pending_state, desired_state, current_state FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=3
0.20 secs : SELECT value, timestamp FROM (SELECT DISTINCT scenedevice_id, value, timestamp FROM realtimedevicedata AS K WHERE K.scenedevice_id=3 AND K.module_id=10 LIMIT 0,100) AS M ORDER BY M.timestamp desc Limit 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT `specenum_id`, `editable`, `default` FROM module_specs WHERE module_id=10
0.00 secs : SELECT * FROM mapitems WHERE id=7
0.00 secs : SELECT lat,lng FROM geoposition WHERE id=46 LIMIT 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT module_id FROM devicedef WHERE deviceenum_id=5
0.00 secs : SELECT id, moduleenum_id, unit FROM module WHERE id=4
0.00 secs : SELECT id, moduleenum_id, unit FROM module WHERE id=10
0.00 secs : SELECT subid FROM devicedef WHERE module_id='4'
0.00 secs : SELECT pending_state, desired_state, current_state FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=6
0.00 secs : SELECT value, timestamp FROM (SELECT DISTINCT scenedevice_id, value, timestamp FROM realtimedevicedata AS K WHERE K.scenedevice_id=6 AND K.module_id=4 LIMIT 0,100) AS M ORDER BY M.timestamp desc Limit 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT `specenum_id`, `editable`, `default` FROM module_specs WHERE module_id=4
0.00 secs : SELECT subid FROM devicedef WHERE module_id='10'
0.00 secs : SELECT pending_state, desired_state, current_state FROM deviceprefs WHERE scenedevice_id=6
0.00 secs : SELECT value, timestamp FROM (SELECT DISTINCT scenedevice_id, value, timestamp FROM realtimedevicedata AS K WHERE K.scenedevice_id=6 AND K.module_id=10 LIMIT 0,100) AS M ORDER BY M.timestamp desc Limit 0,1
0.00 secs : SELECT `specenum_id`, `editable`, `default` FROM module_specs WHERE module_id=10
```

Comment: Hah :) Have a nice day too ;)

Comment: My SQL knowledge saved my life :) added to post.

Answer (score 2):

My general thoughts on this topic are that you should split your code into two main parts:

1. Data extraction
2. Data preparation

In your current implementation you have one query against DB per `foreach()` loop.
Try to do this:

```
$sectorsLiteral = dbGetSectorsByLandId($userLand->id);
$sectorsLiteralIds = array();
foreach ($sectorsLiteral as $sectorLiteral) {
    $sectorsLiteralIds[] = $sectorLiteral["id"]
}

$devicesLiteral = dbGetDevicesBySectorId($sectorsLiteralIds);
```

And so on.

Of course, you'll have to adjust your DB "class" to accept arrays of arguments.

Then, when you'll fetch all data within 3-5 queries, you should work with arrays - again foreaches in foreaches, but they'll work fast, since you don't have to extract data within each loop cycle.

The abstract way of handling all further preparations would be something like below

```
$response = array();
foreach($sectorsLiteral as $sectorLiteral) {
    foreach($devicesLiteral as $deviceLiteral) {
        if ($deviceLiteral['sectorId'] == $sectorLiteral['id']) {
            ...do what you need
        }
    }
}
```

Yes, the code gets more complicated, but it works much faster.

**EDIT**:

One important improvement for your code - you should put your `$connection` to global variables, to avoid opening new one each time the query is sent.

```
$conn = false;

function dbConnect() {
    ...
    global $conn;

    if (!$conn) {
        $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    }
    ...
```

}

The only thing - you will have to find another way of checking the connection status :)

Cheers ;)

Comment: Thank you for do it all that time to answer, I will do these improvements and I'm really thank you but I realize that my SQL execution times is differ too much. I will answer my own question now, reason is not so complex.

Comment: @EnesUnal I am looking forward :)